# How to link scss file with style sheet link tag in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'main', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' =>true  %>
```

Ruby on Rails seems to assume it's a `main.css` and throw an error.

How do I link this correctly to `main.scss`?

Comment: My goal is to load different style sheets for different layouts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only `application.css.scss` is precompiled by default. All files that are required through this file are also compiled. Normally, you would request your other files from within this file using either `*= require_tree` and `*= require_self` or `@import`.

If you still want to explicitly include the `main.css.scss` using `stylesheet_link_tag` like in your question, you need to add it to your list of precompiled assets in `config/initializers/assets/` like so:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( main.css )
```

Comment: My goal is to load different style sheet for 2 different layouts. Importinf them through application.scss load the style sheet for both layouts. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: If that is the case, then your approach of putting it in the layout file is correct. Just make sure to include any file you use here in the `assets.precompile` configuration as I pointed out above.

Comment: As a side note, this worked perfectly, but I also had to restart the rails server.